# What C++ templates issue is going on with this error?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, botan

Running gcc v3.4.6 on the Botan v1.8.8 I get the following compile time error building my application after successfully building Botan and running its self test:

```
../../src/Botan-1.8.8/build/include/botan/secmem.h: In member function `Botan::MemoryVector<T>& Botan::MemoryVector<T>::operator=(const Botan::MemoryRegion<T>&)':
../../src/Botan-1.8.8/build/include/botan/secmem.h:310: error: missing template arguments before '(' token
```

What is this compiler error telling me?  Here is a snippet of secmem.h that includes line 310:

```
[...]
/**
* This class represents variable length buffers that do not
* make use of memory locking.
*/
template<typename T>
class MemoryVector : public MemoryRegion<T>
   {
   public:
      /**
      * Copy the contents of another buffer into this buffer.
      * @param in the buffer to copy the contents from
      * @return a reference to *this
      */
      MemoryVector<T>& operator=(const MemoryRegion<T>& in)
         { if(this != &in) set(in); return (*this); }  // This is line 310!
[...]
```

Comment: @Clever -1er: You've just given 8 points he wouldnt have got for not explaining your problem with the question.

Comment: @sepp2k: True - temporarily slipped my mind...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
{ if(this != &in) this->set(in); return (*this); }
```

I suspect that the `set` function is defined in the base-class? Unqualified names are not looked up in a base class that depends on a template parameter. So in this case, the name `set` is probably associated with the `std::set` template which requires template arguments.

If you qualify the name with `this->`, the compiler is explicitly told to look into the scope of the class, and includes dependent base classes in that lookup.

Comment: Dammit, Johannes! I thought you were a student?! Isn't there anything else you'd rather do on a Saturday night then steeling rep points from old men? `:)` +1 from me anyway.

Comment: @sbi i'm not so much party-compatible :)

Comment: partying is the one thing that takes much less than 10,000 hours to master.

Comment: Well, I'm with Wilhelm on that. (And, FWIW, I wouldn't think Giessen is all that party-compatible either. BICBW.) Anyway, should you happen to come by here (see profile), give me a hint and you're invited to a free beer with a grumpy old man. `:)`

Comment: @Wilhelm oh for poor nerdy litb it takes much more than that